# Trouble resetting path in Laravel project when moving to server

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, configuration

I have the following code in the sites-available/default file:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

server {
listen 80 default_server;
# listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /home/project/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  #  try_files $uri /index.php =404;
  #  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param TENANT $domain;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [auth.login] not found.
in FileViewFinder.php line 137
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('auth.login',     array('/home/vagrant/Code/project/resources/views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
```

/home/vagrant/Code/project was the old path where the project was located when I was developing it locally. Where do I need to reset this "path" to the new one /home/project? This is a Laravel 5 project and I am running an nginx web server.

Comment: deploying to shared hosting or cloud?

Comment: Dedicated server, the server name stuff in the default file is dealing with subdomains.

Comment: Seems Laravel is bootstrapped correctly, but it cannot find the view file. Are you sure the resources directory exists on server?